# Is it possible to use turtlebot 2 with crystal?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I saw that there are not turtlebot debian packages for the crystal release. Is it possible to build it from source for crystal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314379/is-it-possible-to-use-turtlebot-2-with-crystal?/) by [pantphotiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/39777/pantphotiou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends.

If you're using the ROS1 bridge to the navigation stack, 100% absolutely. If you're talking about navigation2, its still highly experimental and not really stable enough for a typical user to treat it like a black box solution.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pantphotiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/39777/pantphotiou/) on 2019-01-31**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-01-31**:
If that answers, can you click the checkbox so it goes off everyone's unanswered questions queue?